# Accessing a Properties File From a Different Project

Tags: java, properties, maven-plugin-development

I am developing a custom maven plugin. When I read my properties file of custom plugin everything is well however when I run it at different project as a plugin how can I get that projects properties file, it always looks at resources directory of itself as usual because of:

I have that:

```
Properties allProperties = new Properties();
allProperties.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/tokens.properties"));
```

and I tried that:

```
Properties allProperties = new Properties();
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
allProperties.load(loader.getResourceAsStream("/tokens.properties"));
```

but didn't work. Any ideas?

**PS:** When I run it it reads from plugins properties file. My properties files are under

```
src/main/resources
```

I use that at my poms:

```
<build>
     ...
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
     ...
</build>
```

and my properties file:

```
project.version = ${project.version}
```

Comment: What directory contains "tokens.properties"?

Comment: Do you want to read a properties file from the JAR of your plugin or one from the directory of the current project loaded in Eclipse?

Comment: @Code-Guru from the other Jar (but the other jar has a dependency to my plugin)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Properties allProperties = new Properties();
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
allProperties.load(loader.getResourceAsStream("/tokens.properties"));
```

You were close. That's indeed the right class loader, but the wrong path. Remove the leading slash.

```
allProperties.load(loader.getResourceAsStream("tokens.properties"));
```